# How to merge sorted lists in C++?

Tags: c++, merge, mergesort

I know this question has been asked multiple times and answered in part on merge sort question but I just can't seem to get it right.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct listNode {
    int info;
    struct listNode *next;
};


struct listNode * addHead(struct listNode* head, int k);
void printAll(struct listNode *head);
struct listNode * deleteLast(struct listNode *head);
struct listNode * append(struct listNode *a, struct listNode *b);
struct listNode * zip(struct listNode *a, struct listNode *b);
struct listNode * merge(struct listNode *a, struct listNode*b);

int main() 
{
    listNode *list1 = 0;
    listNode *list2 = 0;
    listNode *list3 = 0;
    listNode *list4 = 0;
    listNode *list5 = 0;

    //fill list1
    list1 = addHead(list1, 6);
    list1 = addHead(list1, 4);
    list1 = addHead(list1, 2);

    //fill list2
    list2 = addHead(list2, 3);
    list2 = addHead(list2, 1);


    //test deleteLast
    cout << "List 1 contains: " << endl;
    printAll(list1);
    cout << "Deleting last node of List 1. Now contains: " << endl;
    list1 = deleteLast(list1);
    printAll(list1);

    cout << "List 2 contains: " << endl;
    printAll(list2);

    //test append
    cout << "Appending list 1 and list 2 yields: " << endl;
    list3 = append(list1, list2);
    printAll(list3);

    //zip test
    cout << "The zipped list of list 1 and list 2 is: " << endl;
    list4 = zip(list1, list2);
    printAll(list4);

    //merge test
    cout << "The merged list of list1 and list 2 is: " << endl;
    list5 = merge(list1, list2);
    printAll(list5);
    return 0;
}

struct listNode *deleteLast(struct listNode *head) {
    if (head == 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else if (head->next == 0) {
        delete head;
        return NULL;
    } else {
        head->next = deleteLast(head->next);
    }
    return head;
}

struct listNode * addHead(struct listNode *head, int k) {
    listNode *nnode = new listNode;
    nnode->info = k;
    nnode->next = head;
    return nnode;
}

void printAll(listNode *head) {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << endl;
    } else {
        cout << head->info << "->";
        printAll(head->next);
    }
}

struct listNode * append(struct listNode *ahead,struct listNode *bhead) {
    if (bhead == 0) {
        return ahead;
    } else if (ahead == 0) {
        return bhead;
    } else {
        ahead->next = append(ahead->next, bhead);
    }

    return ahead;
}

struct listNode * zip(struct listNode *a, struct listNode *b) 
{
    if (b == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        listNode *tmp = a->next;
        a->next = b;
        a->next = zip(b, tmp);
    }
    return a;
}

struct listNode *merge(struct listNode *a, struct listNode *b)
{
    listNode *result = NULL;
    if (a == NULL)
        return b;
    else if (b == NULL)
        return a;
    if (a->info < b->info) {
        result = a;
        result->next = merge(a->next, b);
    } else {
        result = b;
        result -> next = merge(a, b->next);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now it just doesn't work right. I am getting stuck in an infinite loop then a segmentation fault occurs. Can someone tell me what I have wrong?

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint. Try removing the seemingly functioning parts of your code, the append and zip functions. Just put a comment block around them and rerun the program. You'll see it functions as expected.

The issue here is how you implement these functions. In all cases, you're passing a *pointer* to the listNode, not a copy or anything else. In this case, all changes you make to the object pointed at by the passed pointer are going to be reflected in future calls to any other functions. As such, you're actively modifying the *currently existing* list1 and list2 when you create list3 and list4. They aren't independent lists, they're all made using pointer semantics.

Because of this, you end up with the first element of list2 pointing at list1. If you'd like to see proof, use `printAll()` on list1 and list2 after the execution of `zip()` or `append()`!

Pointers can cause a lot of very unusual seeming problems, but as long as you realize that a pointer is **not the object itself** but instead is a separate value that happens to store the address of the object, you can see how making modifications to a pointed-to object would result in state changes outside of the function.